# Span tag overflows over edge of box

Tags: css, formatting, html

Here is the link to the JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NnQLq/ Sorry for the awkwardness and half completed nature of the fiddle. My css has gotten so complicated, that I can't easily isolate the issue/part of the page. The boxes on the page each contain a tittle. Some of the tittles overflow past the edge of the box. What I want is for them to wrap around the box (like normal text) and then, if they go to many lines down for the box to contain them, a scroll to apear on the edge of the box. Like when `overflow:scroll` is set. I know the last part is somewhat awkward a solution, but the boxes must stay the same size.

For some information, the `box_list_docs_blue` tag is the one that contains the box. It is sometimes pared with the `box_list_docs_gold` tag in css. Use the search page function to find all things pertaining to this class.

Comment: If you add spaces to `dfadfadfadsfadfasdfasdfadfadfasdfadfadffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffdfasdfadfadsfasdf` it works as you want. HTML won't break if there's no spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply `word-wrap: break-word;` to `#name_area`.

```
#name_area {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krish/NnQLq/3/)